# ¿Cómo se dice "watch keeper" en español?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término

Me sorprenderé si alguien puede ayudarme, pero necesito esta pieza de repuesto y cuando vaya al mercado de segunda mano no quiero que crean que estoy hablando de la correa si digo algo como *bucle*. Por lo visto se llama [keeper](https://basicbands.com/fix-a-broken-watch-strap-loop-keeper/) en inglés.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Creo que ayudaría si limitas la pregunta a una región específica. En distintos lugares puede tener diferentes nombres.

Comment: Yo iría a la tienda y le diría "que se me ha roto la cosa esa que sirve para sujetar la correa del reloj en su sitio". :-) Interesante pregunta, nunca me había parado a preguntarme cómo se llama esa pieza.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En México le llamamos aro o bucle retenedor.

Answer (score 5):

Hasta donde yo sé, eso se llama "**presilla**":

> [**presilla**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=U6hJTsj)
>   Del dim. de presa.
>
> 1. f. Cordón o tira pequeña de tela que se pone en una prenda para enganchar un botón o un corchete o para sujetar un cinturón.
> 2. f. Anilla o pieza que sirve para enganchar o sujetar algo.

Una búsqueda en Google de [imágenes de "presilla reloj"](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=presilla%20reloj) parece confirmarlo.

Answer (score 4):

Lo cierto es que nunca me lo había planteado, pero por analogía con los cinturones, yo lo llamaría:

> Pasador

Si bien es cierto que no aparece en el DLE, pero es un nombre común en España para las cintas por las que se introduce el cinturón alrededor de la cintura.

Comment: Así le decimos en Colombia a los dos. El del reloj y el del pantalón.

Answer (score 0):

> **Aviso:** *Escribiose esta respuesta antes de una aclaración en la pregunta; basose en solo la primera imagen que, en retrospectiva, es algo ambigua por cuestión de escala*

Normalmente se llaman **soportes de reloj** o **expositores de reloj**.  Es, por ejemplo, una de las categorías para accesorios en Amazon.  Imagino que tal vez en el pasado fuesen *<sup>porta</sup>/<sub>guarda</sub>rrelojes* o parecido, porque estos términos me dan resultados pero normalmente en joyería tradicional y más bien como cajas expositores.

Comment: Lo que se ve en la foto es el aro que soporta el extremo sobrante de la correa. Ese elemento se encuentra tanto en relojes como en la correa del pantalón y cualquier tipo de correa que sea algo más larga de lo requerido.  No creo que esta sea la respuesta así el OP la haya marcado. Veremos cuando regrese del "mercado de segundas" y nos cuente si la consiguió con ese nombre o no. :-)

Comment: @DGaleano cuando yo contesté lo único que vi fue esa primera imagen, que parece exactamente como un expositor. Si lo que se ve en contexto en la segunda imagen, iba yo buscando una cosa totalmente distinta.  Yo pensaba que era algo como este https://www.alibaba.com/product-detail/for-Casio-Watch-black-acrylic-stand_60492692686.html

Comment: Si. Eso vi.  Cuando respondiste la información era insuficiente. Claro que fue tu idea de ir a Amazon a buscar esa imagen la que me llevó a descubrir la otra imagen y a entender que a la pregunta le faltaba más documentación. Igual no entiendo porque alguien decide votar negativo. Compensaré es negativo con mi +1 :-)